# How to intelligently load pop up form using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, popup, cookies

I have created a jQuery a pop up form which I intend to load each time a user visits to my site. And then prevent it from loading if he hasn't left my site yet. How can I tell jQuery to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set a cookie from the server. If the cookie isn't set, call a jquery method to display the form and set the cookie. if the cookie is set, don't tell jQuery to display the form.

Answer (score 0):

most stimple version: check if document.referrer.indexOf('yourdomain.tld') != -1

you could also use cookies - google will find you some jquery plugins for comfortable cookie handling ...